# sign up form dont load properly profile page in node.js

Tags: node.js, csrf, express-handlebars

in the registration form in my app when i click to register when redirects to the profile page

is appears this error https://prnt.sc/szjbuq

this is my signup.hbs

```
<div class="container mt-5">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-3">

        {{#if hasErrors }}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{#each messages}}
            {{this}}
            {{/each}}
        </div>
        {{/if}}

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                Register Form
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="/user/signup" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{ csrfToken }}">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Signup</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var csrf = require('csurf');
var csrfProtection = csrf();
var passport = require('passport');

router.use(csrfProtection);
```

/* GET users listing. */

```
router.get('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
  var messages = req.flash('error');
  res.render('user/signup', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), messages: messages, hasErrors: 
 messages.length > 0 });
});

router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local.signup', {
  failureRedirect: '/user/signup',
  failureFlash: true
}), (req, res, next) => {
  res.redirect('/user/profile');
});
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
router.get('/signin', function(req, res, next) {
  var messages = req.flash('error');
  res.render('user/signin', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), messages: messages, hasErrors: 
messages.length > 0 });
});

router.post('/signin', passport.authenticate('local.signin', {
  failureRedirect: '/user/signin',
  failureFlash: true
}), (req, res, next) => {
  res.redirect('/user/profile');
});

module.exports = router;
```

profile.hbs

```
 <h1>desde el perfil del usuario</h1>
```

passport.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
var User = require('../models/User');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
    done(err, user);
    })
});
```

//user login

```
passport.use('local.signin', new LocalStrategy({
usernameField: 'email',
passwordField: 'password',
passReqToCallback: true,
}, function (req, email, password, done) {
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is invalid').notEmpty().isEmail();
req.checkBody('password', 'Password is Invalid').notEmpty();

var errors = req.validationErrors();
if (errors) {
    var messages = [];
    errors.forEach(error => {
        messages.push(error.msg);
    })

    return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));
}

User.findOne({ 'email': email }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return done(err);
    if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { 'message': 'No user found' });
    }
    if (!user.validatePassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { 'message': 'Wrong password' });
    }

    return done(null, user);
});
```

}));

//user register

```
passport.use('local.signup', new LocalStrategy({
usernameField: 'email',
passwordField: 'password',
passReqToCallback: true,
}, function (req, email, password, done) {
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is invalid').notEmpty().isEmail();
req.checkBody('password', 'Password is Invalid').notEmpty().isLength({ min: 6 });

var errors = req.validationErrors();
if (errors) {
    var messages = [];
    errors.forEach(error => {
        messages.push(error.msg);
    })

    return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));
}

User.findOne({ 'email': email }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return done(err);
    if (user) {
        return done(null, false, { 'message': 'Email is already in use' });
    }
    var newUser = new User();
    newUser.email = email;
    newUser.password = newUser.hashPassword(password);
    newUser.save((err, result) => {
        if (err) return done(err);

        return done(null, newUser);
    });
});
```

}));

In my terminal appears this:

```
 PS D:\programfiles\vsprojects\shopping-cart\shopping-cart> npm start

 > shopping-cart@0.0.0 start D:\programfiles\vsprojects\shopping- 
 cart\shopping-cart
 > node ./bin/www

 GET / 304 56.821 ms - -
 Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "status" because 
 it is not an "own property" of its parent.
 You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
 See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to- 
 control-prototype-access for details
 GET /stylesheet/style.css 404 21.692 ms - 4539
 GET /user/signup 200 9.842 ms - 3785
 GET /stylesheet/style.css 404 10.594 ms - 4539
 POST /user/signup 302 117.982 ms - 70
 GET /user/profile 404 14.664 ms - 4520
 GET /stylesheet/style.css 404 25.799 ms - 4539
```

anyone can solve this?

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/handlebars-lang/handlebars.js/issues/1642 It seems that you should return JSON formatted objects

Comment: can you explain me how i can do that sry im a bit noob with handlebars

Comment: I think, you sould first try with `res.render('route', . . ., messages: messages.toJSON(), . . .)`

Comment: didnt worked because my problem is on redirecting the page to other not in the render

Comment: Ok. I get it. Can you show what you are doing on the router that goes from `res.redirect('/user/profile');` ??

Comment: the only 2 routes i have are index.js and user.js  you want me to show the code of them?

Comment: I mean, where you define that redirection logic, I assume something like `router.get('/user/profile')`. Maybe your problem is inside that router.

Comment: in profile.hbs i only have this  <h1>desde el perfil del usuario </h1> maybe is something i have in users.js or index.js files

Comment: I'm not really sure. But I think that you, somewhere, are trying to render or return some code from DB that it is not in JSON format. Based on your error, it is caused by Mongoose db. Maybe something you are doing on your `passport.authenticate` code??

Comment: i updated with my passport.js code but i cant seem to find an error

Comment: thank you sergio for your help i solved the problem in user.js i didnt had this code to render the profile page router.get('/profile', (req,res,next) =>{
  res.render('user/profile');
})

Comment: Congrats! As I guessed, your problem seemed to be on the render action ;)

Comment: yes thank you again for the help you where the only one who replied to me